# How to add items on cart list without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have wrote code to add items on cart. I can add items only if reload the page. But I want to add items without reloading the page.
Here is my Script:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addToCart").click(function () {
            var productId = $('#productId').val();
            var productName = $('#productName').val();
            var unitPrice = $('#unitPrice').val();
            var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
            var image = $('#Image').val();
            addItemToCart(productId, productName, quantity, unitPrice, image);
        });
    });

    function addItemToCart(productId, productName, quantity, unitPrice, image) {
        var getProduct = {};
        getProduct.Name = productName;
        getProduct.Image = image;
        getProduct.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        var product = {};
        product.Product = getProduct;
        product.ProductId = productId;
        product.Quantity = parseInt(quantity);
        product.Price = parseFloat(unitPrice) * parseInt(quantity);
        product.Product.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Product/GetCartData",
            data: JSON.stringify(product),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success:function()
            {
                var url = '/Product/Details?ProductId=' + productId;
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is my action addtocart

```
    public JsonResult GetCartData(OrderDetail details)
    {
        if (Session["OrderDetails"] != null)
        {
            orderDetails = (List<OrderDetail>)Session["OrderDetails"];
            int flag = 0;
            foreach (var order in orderDetails)
            {
                if (order.ProductId == details.ProductId)
                {
                    order.Quantity += details.Quantity;
                    order.Price += details.Price;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                orderDetails.Add(details);
            }
            Session["OrderDetails"] = orderDetails;
        }
        else
        {
            orderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
            orderDetails.Add(details);
            Session["OrderDetails"] = orderDetails;
        }
        return Json(orderDetails);
    }
```

here is the layoutpage

```
@using EFreshStore.Models.Context
@using EFreshStore.Models.Context
@{
    List<OrderDetail> orderDetails =new List<OrderDetail>();
    int countItem = 0;
    string totalAmount = "0";
    if (Session["OrderDetails"] != null)
    {
        orderDetails = (List<OrderDetail>)Session["OrderDetails"];
        countItem = orderDetails.Count;
        totalAmount=orderDetails.Sum(c => c.Price).ToString();
    }
    List<ProductUnit> productUnits = (List<ProductUnit>)Session["ProductUnit"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>

</head>
<body class="home-one">

<div class="header-chart">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
        <li class="chart-li">
            <a href="#">My cart</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="header-chart-dropdown">

                        @if (orderDetails!= null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in orderDetails)
                            {
                            <div class="header-chart-dropdown-list">
                                <div class="dropdown-chart-left floatleft">
                                    @foreach (var units in productUnits)
                                    {
                                        if (units.ProductId == @item.ProductId)
                                        {
                                            <a href="#"><img src="~/@units.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageLocation" width="60px" height="60px"alt="cart"></a>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-chart-right">
                                    <h2 class="shopItemTitle">
                                        <a href="#">@item.Product.Name</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <h3>Qty: @item.Quantity</h3>
                                    <h4>৳ @item.Price</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            }
                        }
                        <div class="chart-checkout">
                            <p>subtotal<span>৳ @totalAmount</span></p>
                            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href ='/Order/Cart'" class="btn btn-default">Chckout</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">@countItem items</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cart is on a layout page.
I have created a button click event function to take data.
Then make another function to add items on cart
Is it possible on this ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your entire API is structured. I can see that you are calling POST on "/Product/GetCartData". This is returning a product id. If you can, by the information you have in the client, show the actual product in the cart using that product id, then it can be solved. But it is hard to see as you have not provided more code.

What i am guessing is that you should have an API GET endpoint for the products currently in the cart, and then in the response function of the POST request you should send out a new GET ajax request, where you ask for the products currently in the cart. Then you would avoid a page refresh.

Comment: lets have a look bro. I've updated script and give all of the codes.